# Scroll 2 panels at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll

I have windows forms (.net 2.0) control that contains a splicontainer inside.
Splitcontainer, as usually, contains 2 panels (standard thing). The Autoscroll is set to true.

I've been struggling for quite a time to achieve something like synchronizing those two panels, so scrolling one of these will scroll the second one also. I achieved it - using Scroll event (not a problem).

However, this event is not called when we're tabbing through controls on the one of the panels (e.g. textboxes) - not really like what it's on the msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scroll.aspx ("The Scroll event occurs when the user scrolls through the client area by interacting with the scroll bars, or when the user navigates between controls and the active control scrolls into view. ".

So, in fact, the panels are not really synchronized :|

I'm aware of the fact, that giving focus to not visible control contained in a scrollable control calls it's ScrollToControl(Control) event which "makes" the new control(textbox) visible. To give more details, I can say that both panels are identical (size and controls).

How would you achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4):

Here is exactly what you need to scroll 2 panels in a [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx).  This will scroll even if you are tabbing to controls not in the current view.

```
this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(PanelPaint);
this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(PanelPaint);

Point mPrevPan1Pos = new Point();
Point mPrevPan2Pos = new Point();

void PanelPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
   if (splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition != mPrevPan1Pos)
   {
      splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition = new System.Drawing.Point(-splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, -splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
      mPrevPan1Pos = splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition;
   }
   else if (splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition != mPrevPan2Pos)
   {
      splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new System.Drawing.Point(-splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition.X, -splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
      mPrevPan2Pos = splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition;
   }
}
```

Comment: Working in VS 2012, .Net 4.5, if  I do what you suggest alone, the refresh that resynchronizes the controls occurs eventually, but not soon enough for my liking.

Comment: Why does the autoscroll position of the dependent panel has to be set to the negative of the main panel?

Comment: @MiB_Coder - See the `Note` in this section: [ScrollableControl.AutoScrollPosition Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you place the split container completely in a scrolling thingy instead of putting the scrollbar thingies inside the split container? That way they naturally share the same scrollbar and the split container can be as wide as necessary to fit the entire form.

Comment: errr.
Splitcontainer has 2 controls = panels.
They both are too big to fit, so they need to have separate scrollbars.
I hope that clears a bit.

Comment: I don't have much experience with C# GUIs, but in Java/Swing you can put the 2 big controls in one giant split container in such a way that the split container is big enough to hold them. Of course, such a big split container won't fit in your window so you put it in a scroll pane. I'd be very surprised if you couldn't do this in C# too.

Comment: do you know what is splitcontainer? it has 2 panels and a splitbar. Sure you can create a big one, that will hold 2 panels, but the idea is to let these panels have independant scrollable area.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but I can confirm your solution works in C# too

Answer (score 1):

I took the answer from @SwDevMan81 and rounded it out with the last piece I needed to get it work in VS 2012, .Net 4.5.

Part 1 is inside my form class:

```
    #region Synchronize the scrolling of the two panels in the SplitContainer.

    private Point _prevPan1Pos = new Point();
    private Point _prevPan2Pos = new Point();

    void PanelPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        SynchronizeSplitContainerScrollbars();
    }

    private void SynchronizeSplitContainerScrollbars()
    {
        if (splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition != _prevPan1Pos)
        {
            splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition = new System.Drawing.Point(-splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, -splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
            _prevPan1Pos = splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition;
        }
        else if (splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition != _prevPan2Pos)
        {
            splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new System.Drawing.Point(-splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition.X, -splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
            _prevPan2Pos = splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition;
        } 
    }

    #endregion
```

Part 2 is in the constructor for the Form. I had to add events for the Scroll events themselves.

```
        // Setup so we can synchronize the scrolling of the two panels in the SplitContainer.
        splitContainer1.Panel1.Paint += PanelPaint;
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Paint += PanelPaint;
        splitContainer1.Panel1.Scroll += (obj, scrollEventArgs) => SynchronizeSplitContainerScrollbars();
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Scroll += (obj, scrollEventArgs) => SynchronizeSplitContainerScrollbars();
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the auto-scroll implementations worked for me, but I can confirm that Martijn's solution works and is perfectly synchronised (no delays as events trigger other events).

Place the split container into a panel the size you want to limit the containers to. Disable autoscroll on both panels from your split container, and enable it on the parent panel. From there it actually still didn't work for me (the split container was larger than the panel but didn't trigger the scrollbar for some strange reason, it might work out of the box for you though), so the next step was to trigger the scroll bar appropriately.

There's probably a better way to do this, but I achieved it by adding a label to my panel at the max scroll depth. My split container is populated dynamically (because the UI designer wanted something annoying) so I created the label on the fly in code, but you should get the same effect by putting a similar label in your designer directly (or have it in the designer and just change its position on the fly, you do you).

```
Label invisiLabel = new Label();
invisiLabel.Name = "scrollLabel"; //sorry for the puns
invisiLabel.Text = "";
invisiLabel.Location = new Point(5, height); //you have to work out height yourself
myParentPanel.Controls.Add(invisiLabel);
```

Note for the height, it's not necessarily as simple as height = splitContainer.Height. For me I had to grab the position of the lowest element inside my splitContainer to get an accurate 'height' value for my label. It can also be good to add like 20 or 30 so you get a little padding at the bottom.

tldr; put your split container into a panel, set the panel autoscroll to true, place an empty label inside your scroll panel at the height you want it to scroll to. And don't forget to give your split container all the anchors so it stays with its parent panel.