# AutoScrollPosition Always Returns (0,0) For SplitPanel Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to syncronize the scrolling of two splitcontainers within a splitpanel control. I have the code below:

```
    Point mPrevPan1Pos = new Point(); 
    Point mPrevPan2Pos = new Point(); 

    void PanelPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) 
    { 
       if (splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition != mPrevPan1Pos) 
       { 
          splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition = new System.Drawing.Point(-splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, -splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y); 
          mPrevPan1Pos = splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition; 
       } 
       else if (splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition != mPrevPan2Pos) 
       { 
          splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new System.Drawing.Point(-splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition.X, -splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition.Y); 
          mPrevPan2Pos = splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition; 
       } 
    }
```

However the AutoScrollPosition is always (0,0). I have AutoScroll enabled for both split containers. Why is this? What can I do to get the scroll position?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied the code from this answer: [Scroll 2 panels at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041986/719186)

Did you wire up the events:

```
this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(PanelPaint);
this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(PanelPaint);
```